# How can I get rid of the Google Updater notifications on macOS 13.1?

Tags: macos, install, google-chrome

I keep getting these notifications from system settings telling me that Google Updater has added settings in the background.  It keeps popping up no matter what I do.

I tried deleting Chrome entirely; I have gone into System Settings and turned off Chrome notifications.  I also went into Login Items settings and turned off anything related to Chrome or Google.

I have also done what some other forums have said to do being go into my -

```
~/Library/LaunchAgents

 /Library/LaunchAgents

 /Library/LaunchDaemons
```

-- folders and deleting any files related to Chrome, but I have nothing in the first 2 folders and nothing related to Chrome in the LaunchDaemons folder.

I keep getting these notifications even though Chrome isn't even installed anymore.

Does any one have any recommendations to remove these notifications?